# Find if if a word is contained in a dictionary with path in Python

Tags: python

I have a txt that contains in each line a sentence like this:

```
INT_ASTIK_EAS
ER_ASTOM_ASTIK
and so on.
```

I want to ask for a directory of the main folder that contains the subfolders that each contain the `ASTIK.shp`, then the `EAS.shp`, then the `ASTOM.shp`, etc

`INT` means to perform an intersection with this code where in this case should involve `ASTIK` and `EAS` shapefiles.

```
inte_s=gpd.overlay(ASTIK,EAS,how='intersection')
```

the code:

```
rootdir = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\a' # path to your root directory you walk
sfiles = {} # a dictionary with all the .shp files
for entry in os.listdir(rootdir):
    dirpath = os.path.join(rootdir, entry)
    if os.path.isdir(dirpath): 
        for file in os.listdir(dirpath): # Get all files in the subdirectories
            if file.endswith('.shp'): # If it's an .shp.
                filepath = os.path.join(dirpath, file)
                sfiles[filepath] = gpd.read_file(filepath)


action_dict = {'INT': 'intersection', 'ER': 'difference'}


directory=input('Insert dir of the main folder')
with open(input()) as txtfile: #insert directory of txt
    x = txtfile.readlines()
for line in x:
    action, shape1, shape2 = line.split('_')  # here line is ER_ASTOM_ASTIK or whatever line in the txt file
    if shape1 in sfiles and shape2 in sfiles:
        gpd.overlay(sfiles[shape1], sfiles[shape2], how=action_dict[action])
```

It doesn't probably perform the intersection or difference. How can i store its results in a variable because i have to do further process with the outcomes of every operation of every line.

After checking what's the issue with the `sfiles` variable and what it stores: it gives this:

```
for x in sfiles:
    print (x)

C:\Users\user\Desktop\a\ASTTOM\ASTTOM.shp
C:\Users\user\Desktop\a\PST\PST.shp
```

and finally:

```
if shape1 in sfiles:
    print('success')
else:
    print('failed')

failed
```

which means it doesn't communicate what it should in the dictionary because the shapefiles happen to exist in the folder. How can i make it do the overlay calculations?

```
print(sfiles)

{'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\a\\ASTTOM\\ASTTOM.shp':      OBJECTID  FID_Asttom TheOTA_Tmp  aa    SHAPE_Leng    SHAPE_Area  \
0           1           1      20008   7   4206.346569  5.796467e+05   
1           2           2      20008  11   3311.521073  6.892735e+05   
2           3           3      20008   6   2131.153007  2.196689e+05   
3           4           4      20008   2   1738.249605  4.731495e+04   
4           5           5      20008   1   1075.903789  5.337986e+04   
5           6           6      20008  10   3255.422426  3.628100e+05   
6           7           7      20008   3   2469.427102  2.267493e+05   
7           8           8      20008   5   2466.593786  2.042149e+05   
8           9           9      20008   8   3095.473108  5.384131e+05   
9          10          10      20008   4   1856.659243  1.136976e+05   
10         11          11      20008   9   2293.865083  2.063858e+05   
11         12          12      20104   4   4445.338873  4.455547e+05   
12         13          13      20104   7   3659.621424  2.834771e+05   
13         14          14      20104   2   2098.126160  1.981298e+05
```

it prints the attribute tables of all the shps inside the dictionary

if attempt this:

```
print(sfiles[shape1], sfiles[shape2], action_dict[action])

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-9f435f40293e> in <module>()
----> 1 print(sfiles[shape1], sfiles[shape2], action_dict[action])

KeyError: 'ASTTOM'


and each every time:
print(sfiles[shape1])
KeyError: 'ASTTOM'

print(sfiles[shape2])
KeyError: 'PST'

print(action_dict[action])
difference
```

Basically: there is a dictionary with keys like this: `'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\a\\ASTTOM\\ASTTOM.shp'` and when provide key 'ASTTOM' that is why returns the error.What should i do?Is reading the txt the best procedure?

Comment: The arguments you are providing aren't valid keys. You need to convert them into appropriate keys, i.e. the relevant directory path as a string.

Comment: Can you show your version?

Comment: I don't know what format the keys come in/what the function mapping the values from the text file to them would be. It *seems* (based on the single example provided) that it would be `'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\a\\{}\\{}.shp'.format(shape1, shape1)`.

Comment: I can't understand.Tell me what info you need to post, what variables to run in order to help you help me.I ve been trying this thing for 2 days and can't figure it out.Thanks